# C-sharp Arrays with Unity3d

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I see some forum post and some said that array in the Unity3D is not a real array. Well,I don't really understand that.

My 1st question is how to add items into an array? Is it Array.Push() or Array.Add()?

My 2nd question is how to clear item from an array? Is it Array.Clear(arrname,0,arrname.Length)?

My 3rd question is arrays like int[], string[] and so on, how to clear items and add items? I didn't find any real answer for this.

Sorry for my bad English and I some dumb question here.I hope that someone can explain to me about this.Thanks.Enjoy your day.

Comment: Which forum post claims that Unity3D arrays are not "real" arrays? That sounds misleading to start with - and it sounds like you should really be asking the person who originally posted that what they meant...

Comment: What is a "real" array? What's a not real array? What's the difference?

Comment: You need to boil your question down to a single problem, and preferably you shouldn't be asking simple questions the answers to which are a single google* search away - such as the use of well documented classes like `Array`.

(*Other search engines are available.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C# you can't *change* array's *length* anyhow (by adding/removing/clearing items); but you can *recreate array*:

```
  int[] array = new int[] {1, 2, 3};

  // Add item simulation
  int[] array = array.ToList().Add(4).ToArray();

  // Remove 2-nd item (that is 3) simulation
  int[] array = array.ToList().RemoveAt(2).ToArray();

  // Clear simulation: just an array recreation
  int[] array = new int[] {};
```

If you want a *data structure* which *looks like array* but allows you to add/delete/clear, `List<T>` is the first thing you can check:

```
  List<int> list = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};
  // Just add 
  list.Add(4);
  // ... remove
  list.RemoveAt(2);
  // and clear
  list.Clear();
```

Comment: Not true, you can change an array length by calling Array.Resize(ref array, your_length); http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: it is true, Array.Resize creates a new Array and copys all elements of the old array into the new array and then sets the reference to the new array. He gave a good in-depth answer to a question that doesnt show a lot of insight. I wouldnt downvote this.

Comment: Although the answer was in-depth I think that is the problem: it was too in-depth, for the nature of the question. Which, as you say, didn't demonstrate much in the way of research. Casting an array to a list, to add something to it, and then back to array (while a valid approach) doesn't seem to directly answer the basic questions asked. And as Mo Patel says, there is actually an Array.Resize method.

Comment: Even without looking at the question and the specific answer. The answer was right and he said it wasnt and downvoted for that reason. I wanted to clarify that and then even added another reason why not to downvote this answer(which might be a bit controversial)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation,may be I try to use list because it look like array need to be resize 1st before it add items.